# Magento removing widget from layout

Tags: magento, layout, widget

How can I remove widget from layout? I added *category_widget_link* using install script, deleted that widget from database directly (I know I shoudn't :) ) and after that in admin panel too. It still shows up. Thanks for the answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use xml to remove (`<remove name="search correct block">`)

Example go to the page or category in magento in admin part of xml scripts and place , your header of the page or category will disappear, you just find the straight-laced block name and removing it, look for the name him in the layout / folder widget.xml will be somewhere

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still didn't resolve my issue. I tried to put this in my local.xml file (in default handle) but it still doesn't remove links. (My links are placed in top menu)                            <reference name="top.menu">                                   <remove name="catalog_category_link"/>                   </reference>

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone need the answer for this.

I noticed that there're still some record left behind in the "widget_instance_page_layout" table.

So all we need to do is delete the record that's still left behind inside the "layout_update" table in your database after you remove the widget.